# Pass an incoming variable with WPF by the user used in a class c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My goal is to transmit an incoming variable by the user in a file user.xaml (in a textBox) and to return this variable in a class

```
<UserControl .....>
 <Grid x:Name="GridGlobal">
 <DockPanel Background="White" Margin="5" >
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0 10 0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCommandeUrl"  Width="500" 
                   Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                <mui:ModernButton x:Name="btnSave" Content="{x:Static 
                   p:Resources.Link_Save_Link}" Click="BtnSave_Click" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding 
                  NextCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding 
                NextEnabled}"/>                        
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to receive my **txtCommandeUrl** in a class.cs.

I want to use this urlCommandeUrl in my class and thinks of all

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please make sure to take an opportunity to read [ask] and check out other resources in the [help].  Your question is... well, not a question.  What is it you're having a problem with, *specifically*?

Comment: Take a look at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you search for this :

Add this function on the user.xaml.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method called on button click.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The <see cref="object"/> sender of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The Routed event arguments <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/>.</param>
    private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // string cmdUrl = txtCommandeUrl.Text;

        // i want to use cmdUrl in other class.cs
        OtherClass.CmdUrl = txtCommandeUrl.Text;
    }
```

And in the other class :

```
public OtherClass 
{
   public CmdUrl { get; set; } 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use both `Button.Click` and `Button.Command`, choose one.

And you should choose command:

```
   <mui:ModernButton x:Name="btnSave" Content="{x:Static 
                   p:Resources.Link_Save_Link}"
                   Command="{Binding NextCommand}"
                   CommanParameter="{Binding ElementName="txtCommandeUrl", Path=Text}"
/>
```

As for IsEnabled, when you bind ICommand to a button, it reads `ICommand.CanExecute` to enable/disable itself.

In general, if you want to make apps in WPF, read into MVVM and some UI framework, like for example [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) or MVVMLight - it will save you a lot of time after you master one of them